# opencv qt display Video

Tags: c++, qt, opencv

This code to display a video using opencv with Visual studio

i have been looking everywhere for a tutorial how to use Qt with opencv to display video
but i couldn't find any :/

is there anyone here knows how to do that?

```
#include <opencv\highgui.h>
#include <opencv\cv.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
CvCapture* capture1 = cvCreateFileCapture("c:\\VideoSamples\\song.avi"); 
IplImage* frame1;
cvNamedWindow( "display video1", CV_WINDOW_AUTOSIZE ); 


while(1) 
 {
 frame1 = cvQueryFrame( capture1 ); 
 cvSmooth( frame1, out, CV_GAUSSIAN, 17, 17 );
 if( !frame1 ) break;
 cvShowImage( "display video1", frame1 ); 

 char c = cvWaitKey(33);
 if( c == 27 ) break; 
 }
 cvReleaseCapture( &capture1 );
 cvDestroyWindow( "display video1" ); 
 }
```

Comment: Are you sure it `must` to be Qt? I.e. is the highgui not enough for your purpose?

Comment: im a student doing my internship nowadays. i was asked by my boss to use openCV and visual studio to display a video after i did that he asked me to use QT instead of Visual studio :/

Answer (score 1):

You can easily display a cv::Mat in a QLabel:

Assuming frame is your current RGB-videoframe with 8bit depth as cv::Mat-object and label is a pointer to your QLabel:

```
//convert to QPixmap:
QPixmap pixmap = QPixmap::fromImage(QImage((uchar*)frame.data, frame.cols, frame.rows, frame.step, QImage::Format_RGB888));

//set scaled pixmap as content:
label->setPixmap(pixmap.scaled(frame.cols, frame.rows, Qt::KeepAspectRatio));
```

Answer (score 0):

For starters, you've got to make sure that the OpenCV libraries you are using have been built with Qt support.

You will probably need to download the source code (available on [Github](https://github.com/itseez/opencv)), configure the build using [CMake](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/resources/software.html), and re-build them yourself.  [Here](http://docs.opencv.org/doc/tutorials/introduction/windows_install/windows_install.html) is the link to the guide on how to build the OpenCV libraries from source.

Once that is done, [this](http://code.google.com/p/qt-opencv-multithreaded/) is an example of how to capture frames from a camera (just swap camera with file for your case) and display the frames to a window, making use of the Qt framework.

Hope this helps you.